# Accessing contents of file uploaded in one html page in another page

Tags: javascript, file-upload, web-applications

How do I access the data, say text file, uploaded in one html page in another?

I have home.html where the data is uploaded and once the data is loaded successfully I want the user to be able to click a icon and then access the visualization(bar chart) created out the data uploaded. I am not sure how to make javascript pass the particular contents to another html page

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this several ways. More simple way -  just include loaded data to you page and process it after load by js. More complex is to use FileAPI for getting file data from backend after loading.